# Adopt custom allocators into an existing real-world project : chain of command (using RAII?)

Tags: multithreading, c++11, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, raii

I am working on a game project.
Below is a simplified diagram of the whole architecture.

(No need to concern much about the class / function names.)

[image]

(Amount of classes/ functions in real program = 100x+)

From above diagram, all code can be roughly divided into 3 layers. (red/orange/green)

- **Red:**  (I call them "**The big guys**")
  Every `System_XXX` are derived from `System_Default`.
  They call below layers, and sometimes call other red.
- **Orange:**
  It contains a lot of game-specific library.
  In short, they are just a utility to support the red.
- **Green:**
  It is a utility to support red and orange.
  It contains all of basic function.
  The code is designed to be used by  many games.
  Most heap allocation (99% of new/delete) happen here.

Here is a snippet show how most functions are called:-

```
class System_EnemyAI : public System_default{
    public: void update(){
        EntityPointer entity= .... ;
        systemGet<System_Projectile>()->damage(entity);
        //^ system always call another system using this template function
        // "systemGet<System_XXX>() is a function in class "System_default"
        TempMathState mathState;
        mathState.someFunction( .... ); 
        ......
    }
    //... other member / function
}
class TempMathState{
    MyArray<float> stateList; //<-- need dynamic allocation
    //...... other member / function
}
```

Everything works fine until my greedy boss tell me that I should use **custom allocators**.

### The proposal

- Each **big guy** (`System_XXX`) should have its own memory pool to promote data-coherence.
  **Definition:** `System_XXX` = all systems that derived from `System_Default`.
  **Advantage:** Less fragmentation, less cache miss, sound good!
- We know that 99% of function flow can be depicted similar as the black chains of command (below diagram).

[image]

- **In the left chain (1)**, starts at `findThreat()`,
  the big guy in this chain is `System_EnemyAI`.
  Therefore, all memory allocation in the chain should use memory pool of `System_EnemyAI`.
- **In the right chain (2)**, starts at `update()`,
  the **last** big guy in this chain is `System_Projectile` (via `::damage(entity)`).
  Therefore, all memory allocation in the chain should use memory pool of `System_Projectile`.

The logic looks reasonable, everyone agrees, end of meeting.

## Question

What is the least painful approach to achieve this?

**Soft requirement:-**

- I don't have to refactor most function of most classes.
- It should support multi-threading.

## My poor solutions

All three approaches share a certain disadvantage :-
I have to add at least one statement in every function in **System**(red)-layer.

### Solution 1 (one additional parameter)

Pass custom allocator down to the chain.
Most functions in all layers have to receive `allocator` as a parameter.

```
class System_EnemyAI : public System_default{
    public: void update(){
        .....
        systemGet<System_Projectile>()->damage(this->allocator,entity); //ugly
        TempMathState mathState=TempMathState(this->allocator); //ugly

    }
}
```

**Disadvantage:**

- That would be an exhaustive refactoring!
- All code will look more ugly.

### Solution 2A (global variable)

Set a static global flag.

```
class System_EnemyAI : public System_default{
    public: void update(){
        GLOBAL_HEY_USE_ALLOCATOR = this->allocator;
        .... other code ...
        systemGet<System_Projectile>()->damage(entity); //don't change :)
        GLOBAL_HEY_USE_ALLOCATOR = this->allocator;     
        //^ #steal the flag back,
        //     because it was stolen by System_Projectile (see below)
        TempMathState mathState=TempMathState();        //don't change :)

    }
}
```

It have to do in all function :-

```
class System_Projectile : public System_default{
    public: void damage(EntityPointer entity){
        GLOBAL_HEY_USE_ALLOCATOR = this->allocator;  //#steal the flag
        .... other code ...
    }
}
```

`#steal` : because the callee function (`System_Projectile`) will set `GLOBAL_HEY_USE_ALLOCATOR`, so caller (`System_EnemyAI`) have to set `GLOBAL_HEY_USE_ALLOCATOR` back.

Any allocation will use the `Allocator* GLOBAL_HEY_USE_ALLOCATOR` as a memory pool.
This part is not hard.

**Disadvantage:**

- It uses global flag, so it doesn't support multi-threading.
- I have to set many flags manually.

### Solution 2B (RAII : STACK global variable)

Use RAII to limit scope and manipulate constructor/destructor :-

```
class System_EnemyAI : public System_default{
    public: void update(){
        AllocatorScope scope = AllocatorScope(this->allocator);
        //^ push "this->allocator" into a global stack
        .... other code ...
        systemGet<System_Projectile>()->damage(entity); //don't change :)
        TempMathState mathState=TempMathState();        //don't change :)

    }
};
class System_Projectile : public System_default{
    public: void damage(EntityPointer entity){
        AllocatorScope scope = AllocatorScope(this->allocator);  
        .... other code ...
        //the "scope" is deleted, so pop stack to recover the previous state
    }
};
```

**Disadvantage:**

- It still uses global variable, so it doesn't support multi-threading.

Comment: Solution 2C: RAII stack, but with a `thread_local` variable?

Comment: @Quentin Sir, you really understand the question, thank!   Your approach is promising.    How a thread can have a local variable?  and...  How `System_XXX` can access the thread variable?  Is it possible for a `System_XXX` function to know which thread is calling itself (without significant performance penalty & without get an additional parameter)?  Is there any clean way?

Comment: This isn't much more than a first, rough idea. But you can declare variables as [`thread_local`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), which behave just like global variables except that each thread gets its own, there's no interaction. Since your goal is to create a pseudo-parallel-callstack, this looks like a useful tool.

Comment: @Quentin  Thank, I will take a deep look into it.